# In KDE, can one use 'Save session' to restore, upon reboot, an application that runs under Wine?

Tags: kde, wine, kubuntu, kde5

I am using `Kubuntu 20.04`. When I manually save the session (`KDE Menu` -> `Leave` -> `Save session`), some applications are restored upon reboot, and some aren't. For example, `PDF-XChange Editor`, which runs under `Wine`, is not restored.

Is there a way to make it so that `PDF-XChange Editor`, running under `Wine`, is restored upon reboot?

My system info:

`Kubuntu 20.04`
`KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8`
`KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0`
`Qt Version: 5.12.8`